# Spring OAuth2 and authentication/authorizatiuon in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, spring, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have implemented Spring Boot back-end application with RESTful web services secured by OAuth2.

Right now I'm working on my client-side application which should be written in AngularJS.

During the developing back-end application in order to authenticate/authorize user previously for tests I used following command(for example with curl):

```
curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=password1&username=username1&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"
```

Right now I'm thinking on the approach for user authentication/authorization from client side (from AngularJS application).

I don't think it is safe to place somewhere at client side(internet browser) information like `client_secret` and `client_id`. Am I correct ? If so, could you please tell me the correct approach how the user can be authenticated with my OAuth2 and AngularJS without security violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 support different Grant-Types (sometimes called "flows"). OAuth has a special Grant-Type for your use case: [implicit grant](https://labs.hybris.com/2012/06/05/oauth2-the-implicit-flow-aka-as-the-client-side-flow/) - it works without client secret.